# Detect the taxonomy term(s) of a node from within a template file

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a Drupal 7 site with a content type of event.

I have a taxonomy called "event types" that has 5 options (Party, Conference, Meeting, etc)

I have one template named node--event.tpl.php for styling the standalone event nodes.

How can I detect which taxonomy terms apply to a given event node from within the template file? I need to change some of the presentation logic based on the taxonomy term associated with the event.

I am not using the taxonomy in the URL, so I need to find another method for detecting the event type. Devel doesn't seem to show me any values of taxonomy terms to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the first answer, you should use a preprocess function, but probably for the node template.

For the `node.tpl.php` template (and all derivatives) the function is defined as

```
MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
}
```

and should appear your theme's `template.php` file.

You must clear the Drupal cache in order to reset the theme registry such that Drupal recognizes and executes this function.

The `$vars` argument of the function is an array that contains all the template variables which subsequently appear in the tpl file (`$vars['foo']` will be leveraged as `<?php print $foo; ?>` in the tpl file).

This also includes the native `$node` object, which will allow you to inspect `$node->taxonomy`, and create any subsequent variables accordingly. You can leverage these in the tpl file.

The best way to inspect and discover the components of `$vars` is to use the Devel module's `dpm()` function, which nicely prints any variable to the theme's messages box.

So, enable devel, create the following in `template.php`, clear cache, refresh viewing a node, and work from there.

```
MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  dpm($vars);
}
```

You may also be interested in my [session on Drupal preprocess functions](http://www.archive.org/details/ThemePreprocessFunctionsAnIntroduction_383) from Drupalcon Copenhagen or the [Drupal handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/223430).

Comment: It may also be worth adding that you can alter the template which is used in the preprocess function. So that node--event--<term>.tpl.php is used.